# Help me Obi Wan Kenobi.... I need some assistance with understanding etherscan and where my erc20 tokens went

Tags: etherscan, myetherwallet

First post, thanks in advance for any help.  Back in early 2018 I setup some friends with  MEW wallet when they had purchased some Trx while it was still and erc20 token.  I know mainnet happened etc and they basically never looked or did anything with it and just asked yesterday about getting it moved over or traded to mainnet via Binance.  When I opened their wallet today we didn't see the trx tokens, about 102k.  I followed the custom token instructions add instructions from the medium post and still nothing.  I can see some type of action happened and that the tokens were there and interacted with the trx contract but I'm just at a loss I can't tell if they went to some type of contract holding or maybe to binance.  It is possible we had consolidated their tokens to another wallet and they accidentally made a copy of the wrong paper wallet but I can't tell.  Could drop some knowledge on me here as to what happened?
Here's the wallet address:  0xdC1D5aAc95a29a5Ee9938aa09397a679180Bc894

only 2 transactions with it so not a lot to sort through.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to contact Binance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token funds were transferred to 0x81c36E2aFE4FFCDD4F4F09514BE3fFD94732D892, and after to Binance ('0x3f5CE5FBFe3E9af3971dD833D26bA9b5C936f0bE').

Just go to the Erc20 Token Txns tab to check it.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the info..  I thought that is what happened but I just wasn't positive, now I know what to tell them.